# g++ linking libs instead of *.o containing static members leads to segfault

Tags: static, linker, g++

I observed segfaults if I used linking libraries instead of linking all the primary compiler output with g++. This problem occurs with libraries with classes with static members. And I don't find a solution with libs. What went wrong?

Simplified: I created two libraries called alpha and beta. Alpha contains a static member (race conditions were excluded). The library alpha depends on beta. And alpha and beta depend on a third library, the public library gamma (in my case Cairo).

The static member is defined as private within a class Alpha and access via getters and setters with mutex locks.

I compile my the source code for alpha

```
g++ -fPIC -DPIC `pkg-config --cflags gamma` alpha*.cpp -c
ar rcs alpha.a alpha*.o
```

and beta, respectively

```
g++ -fPIC -DPIC `pkg-config --cflags gamma` beta*.cpp -c
ar rcs beta.a beta*.o
```

Now, I want to use these libs (alpha, beta, and gamma) in my program delta. I tried two different ways to compile and link in two steps. First, compile and simply link the compiled objects:

```
g++ -fPIC -DPIC `pkg-config --cflags gamma` delta.cpp -c -o delta.o
g++ -fPIC -DPIC alpha*.o beta*.o delta.o `pkg-config --libs gamma` -o delta
```

This compiles, links and runs. Without any problems.

But if I want to use the .a libs instead and try:

```
g++ -fPIC -DPIC `pkg-config --cflags gamma` delta.cpp -c -o delta.o
g++ -fPIC -DPIC -lalpha -lbeta delta.o `pkg-config --libs gamma` -o delta
```

This compiles and links. But produces a segfault on running. During the very first access to the static member.

Answer (score 0):

> `g++ -fPIC -DPIC -lalpha -lbeta delta.o` pkg-config --libs gamma `-o delta`

Note that this command line is generally incorrect. See [this post](https://eli.thegreenplace.net/2013/07/09/library-order-in-static-linking). You *should* use this command instead:

```
g++ delta.o -lalpha -lbeta `pkg-config --libs gamma` -o delta
```

This may or may not solve your crash.

---

In general, you are *probably* depending on the order of initialization of globals, which is somewhat hard to control. The best advice is to *not* do that.

---

What do I mean by order of initialization? Consider these two files:

```
// a.cc
const int foo = 42;

// b.cc
extern int foo;
const int bar = foo;
```

Question: what is the value of `bar`?
Answer: you can't generally tell. It could be `0`, `42`, and I believe could also be some other random value.

Comment: You are right with the second point (and also with the first point, but this turned out to be the minor problem). My code (and your demonstration) was a nice example of the static/global init fiasco.